# Set a JSDoc comment to generate API documentation without adding a TypeScript declaration to the .d.ts file

Tags: typescript, jsdoc, typescript-declarations, typescript-definitions, api-documentation

I'm writing in JS, and I use JSDoc comments to generate both my API documentation and my TypeScript declaration files. However, I have a couple of functions that I'd like to keep out of my TS code -- but I still want to include them in my API reference docs. Is this possible? Is there any sort of tag that tells JSDoc, "document this function but leave it out of the `.d.ts` file"?